# Avoid html table flickering on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to avoid html table flickering on mouse hover. when someone hover a row it shows a button, but the table seems a litlle bit weird.

Here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/7nqLg/2/

Comment: Can't you just show the buttons the whole time? They are what's pushing the height and width and making it 'flicker'.

Comment: I dont see any table flickering.. only the row size is increasing to accommodate the button..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead.

```
jQuery('.myRow').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('div:first').css('visibility', 'visible');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('div:first').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

And instead of hiding the element set its visibility to `hidden` and on mouse over make it `visible`, this will avoid the flickering because the div occupies some space when you show it. Making its visibility hidden will still occupy the space but won't be displayed.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/7nqLg/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the default height of the TD to match the maximum height on a row when the extra elements are exposed.

So the CSS for "myRow" TDs need to have a min-height of 45 pixels.

```
.myRow td {
    height:45px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make the padding of the `td` 2px..  or increase the height of the row -- td which can accommodate the 8px on the button aswell.. its currently at 8px,hence causeing the increase in the height of the row..